# How to convert Calendar to java.sql.Date in Java?

Tags: java, sql, calendar

```
Calendar cal;
String sql = "INSERT INTO ttable (dt) values (?);"
//dt is a dateTime field in ttable

PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

stmt = setDate(1,cal); //not working

stmt.execute();
stmt.close();
```

I would like to convert cal to a Date type to insert into table.

Comment: presumably you wanted `java.sql.Date` and not `java.util.Date`?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There is a [`getTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) method (unsure why it's not called getDate).

**Edit:** Just realized you need a java.sql.Date. One of the answers which use `cal.getTimeInMillis()` is what you need.

Comment: it is `getTime()` because it returns the exact Time like `Wed Dec 05 10:57:35 GMT+03:30 2018`, not just date.

Comment: getTime() returns java.util.Date not java.sql.Date. Question was to get java.sql.Date.

Answer (score 35):

Did you try `cal.getTime()`? This gets the date representation.

You might also want to look at the javadoc.

Comment: Yes, but I keep needing to cast with (Date).

Comment: That's because you need a java.sql.Date (like James Jithin said) and Calendar.getTime() provides you with a java.util.Date.

Answer (score 35):

Use `stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()))`

Answer (score 11):

Converting is easy, setting date and time is a little tricky. Here's an example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2000);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple way to convert `Calendar` values into `Date` instances.

```
Calendar C = new GregorianCalendar(1993,9,21);

Date DD = C.getTime();

System.out.println(DD);
```

Comment: The question specifically asked about java.sql.Date. There are several answers like this one, all assuming java.util.Date. Of course, some would say naming these the same thing was a stupid idea.

Answer (score 4):

`stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime()));`

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); //This to obtain today's date in our Calendar var.

java.sql.Date date = new Date (cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this code works:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss");    
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2013,0,31);
System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

you can find the rest in this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-date-and-calendar-examples/