# Hibernate Query to fetch records on date ignoring the year

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to fetch all the records which match the today date but ignoring the year Date in database is like this `1980-11-14`. Want to fetch the record only comparing month and day not the year. I tried it using `Criteria` but its not working. Here is my code.

```
Date date = new Date(); // your date
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

Calendar fromDate = calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

Calendar toDate = calendar.getInstance();

Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Add_Follower.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("follow_uInfo.id", uid));
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("following_uInfo.dob",fromDate,toDate));
users=criteria.list();
```

Comment: Well, Abhi, what happened?  Did you get it to work?

Comment: I am geting exception org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: Following_uInfo of: com.abhi.model.Add_Follower

Comment: @MikeNakis I just want it to know setting the constant year how can it will work I tried it giving the casting exception java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to java.util.Date.

Comment: Regarding `could not resolve property`, I do not know, that's your code and your properties, you should be able to tell what's wrong, but I see that in one case you say `follow_uInfo` and in another case you say `following_uInfo`, could that be a hint?

Comment: As to how to convert a calendar to date, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/9112770/773113

Comment: its self join property both are the different field from relation table?

Answer (score 1):

I did it with a named query and using "EXTRACT",

in this example for birthdays:

```
SELECT p FROM Person p 
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.gebdat) = EXTRACT(DAY FROM NOW())
AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p.gebdat) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM NOW())
ORDER BY p.nachname, p.vorname
```