# Error when trying to cast from Calendar to Date then to sql.Date

Tags: java

```
enter code here: Calendar startydate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Date srtsqldate = (Date) startydate.getTime();
                    String srtstrdate = String.valueOf(srtsqldate);
                    Calendar expydate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

I then want to setDate in a PreparedStatement st1.setDate(7,srtsqldate);, but I keep getting ERROR: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class java.sql.Date (java.util.Date is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'

Comment: I found this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9112770/how-to-convert-calendar-to-java-sql-date-in-java . But I don't seem to be able to use getTimeInMillis(),

Comment: java.sql.Date srtsqldate = new java.sql.Date(startydate.getTimeInMillis());

Comment: Closed as duplicate of the question you linked to yourself. Seems you didn't read far enough, i.e. at what is currently the [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9112846/5221149), which is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: FYI, `Date` and `Calendar` are terrible classes that were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes.